# Extracting connected lines from ordered dataset

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataset similar to the one shown below, with several disconnected smooth curves. Instead of drawing markers, I want to connect the markers within each curve by a line. How to do this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed = 42

x = np.linspace(0.1,0.9,50)
y = x%1
x += np.sin(2*x%1)
y = y%0.2


plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.savefig("test.pdf")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing a line plot can be done using `plot` instead of `scatter`. Here the problem is that **all** of the points will be connected. 
So using `plt.plot(x,y)` would result in something like this
[image]

The idea would be to split the lines at the positions where they should be discontinuous. We can use the fact that a point where one coordinate is a `nan` value is not shown and breaks the line.

One would the need to find out the positions where to split. In this case it's rather simple: It is where the derivative with respect to x or y is negative.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0.1,0.9,50)
y = x%1
x += np.sin(2*x%1)
y = y%0.2

def split(x,y):
    ind = np.arange(0,len(x)-1)[np.diff(y) < 0]+1
    return np.insert(y, ind, np.nan), np.insert(x, ind, np.nan)

x,y = split(*split(x,y))


plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to first detect the markers that form the perceived lines.

Your data is just a bunch of dots, and I bet the consecutive dots in the list *don't* form neat lines. The structure is detected by your brain when you look at the plotted picture, not by your code.

A likely tool is a clustering algorithm (several implementations exist, e.g. in `scikit`).

Comment: You are absolutely right, in principle the data may be disordered and I would require some clustering algorithm. However, the way i stated the question ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer is the correct one, so I accepted that one.